# Should Javascript be separated into files by page or consolidated into one file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Should I be separating my js for each page assuming there is no overlap and putting references on each page instead of having one master file? what is typical practice? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that is common to every page of your site should be on a single file, since it will be loaded only once by the browser.

Code specific for a single (or maybe 2) page(s) should go on separate files, loaded only by the pages that need them.

That's the way I do it: you use the browser's cache to reduce your bandwidth and to accelerate the loading and rendering of the page.

Comment: Its a bit of a balancing act.  1 file is great for less HTTP overhead, but if that was originally 3 cachable files, and you need to make a single change to one of them, the user has to re-download all 3 file's content to get the change.  If it were 3 separate files, only the file modified would need to be downloaded.  Scripts are also blocking, thus if you can push any of them to the bottom of the page (may require splitting) there is a perf boost.

Answer (score 2):

For infrequently accessed pages, load the javascript inline (at bottom of all the markup) for quickest load time (one less TCP connection required as is the case for separate .js script file).

For frequently hit pages do the opposite: reference a .js script file -  in this case the caching by the browser provides a greater advantage across the aggregate of page loads.

In larger projects, develop your javascript in separate .js files (you can use the module pattern for instance), then for production compile them into a single file (or a number of files per architecture of your application) with a build script.

Comment: developing with separate js files has the advantage that they can be merged into one using a simple build script, but splitting a single file into multiple pieces is much harder.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what kind of app you have. If your app is frequently accessed but for short periods of time then initial loading time is important and you should try to combine files.

If, however, you expect users to spend hours at a time in your app and initial load time is not critical then I would advise partitioning your .js files as much as you need to to make it readable - since they will all be cached anyway after the initial load.

Don't believe the hype. Unless you're a google search engine you should be careful not to sacrifice readability for the sake of a few seconds (or less) at initial start up. Put it another way, rules of thumb are just that, don't neurotically follow them - think first :-)